# Use StreamSubscription as Future in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, future

I want to connect my Flutter app to bluetooth device with flutter_blue library, and return a result (anything) when the connection is ON. But I don't understand how to do.
Here my code :

> Future connect(BluetoothDevice device) async {
> _btDevice = device;

```
StreamSubscription<BluetoothDeviceState> subscription;
subscription = device.state.listen((event) async {
  if (event != BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
    await device.connect();
  } else {
    await device.discoverServices().then((value) => _initFeatures(value));
  }
})
  ..onDone(() {
    // Cascade
    print("onDone");
  });

subscription.asFuture();
//subscription.cancel();
```

}

And when I call this function with

> ```
> await newDevice.connect(bluetoothDevice).then((value) => print('OK'));
> ```

OK is written before the real connection. _initFeatures if well call when the device is connected.

I try to use asFuture from StreamSubscription with onDone, but that change nothing.

Could you help me please ?

UPDATE 12/10
I've worked on another project for few monthes, and when I come back, I can't solve the problem, so I add the full code.
The concept is a class widget calls the connect future in other class and need to receipt the end of work.

Widget

```
Future<void> _connectDevice() async {
try {
  widget.device.connect(widget.btDevice!).then((value) => _initValue());
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

_initValue() is a method to create the rest of the screen

and the Future connect()

```
  Future connect(BluetoothDevice device) async {
_btDevice = device;

StreamSubscription<BluetoothDeviceState> subscription;
subscription = device.state.listen((event) async {
  if (event != BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
    await device.connect();
  } else {
    await device
        .discoverServices()
        .then((value) => _initFeatures(value))
        .then((value) => print("OK"));
  }
});

await subscription.asFuture();
await subscription.cancel();
```

}

What I'd like is the Future finishes when `print("OK")` is called, in order `.then((value) => _initValue());` is called.
The problem is only this end. Maybe it's not the good way to implement this kind of solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `package:flutter_blue` is supposed to be used, but 1. [`Stream.listen`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/listen.html)'s `onData` callback is expected to return `void`.  This means that its return value will be ignored, so if you pass an asynchronous callback, there will be no direct way to know when that callback completes. 2. Your example calls `subscription.asFuture()` but doesn't `await` it, so nothing will wait for the subscription to run to completion.

Comment: Also, it's not necessarily a problem, but it's usually inconsistent to use both `await` and `Future.then`.  `await` is syntactic sugar for creating a `Future.then` callback for you.  Just use `await`.

Comment: I know for the unecessity to combine await and then, but sometime (with showDialog for exemple), only await seems to be not sufficient

Comment: This is late to the game, but please note that [StreamSubscription.listen](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/StreamSubscription/asFuture.html) _overwrites_ the onDone and onError callbacks, so calling that after listen is eliminating the onDone callback you defined in the first part of your snippet

Comment: I finally find a solution. In `_connectDevice` I sent a callback to the Future which is the method I wanted to be called back, and when the StreamSubscription is finished, it runs the callback

Comment: @Turvy pls add you solution, I am curious how you did it! Thank you